# Open Link in Browser from iframe Phonegap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, iframe, phonegap-plugins

i use phonegap 3.3 and angularjs to build a app.
I load a content in iframe .
In this iframe there are a lot of links that open pdf and html pages in the app .
I want to open links in new browsers..
I tried InAppInABrowser but it doesn't work .
Any solution ?

The structure is :

```
...
   <iframe src="http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/test.html" >
...
```

in http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/test.html there are a lot of :

```
... 
   <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.open(url,"_blank");'>text</a> 
...
```

Thanks Carlo